# Wrapping CLR DLL in a native DLL

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll

I am new to C++, visual studio and such, meaning also that my technical language is lacking so please bear with me. What i need to do is the following: take a CLR DLL containing C++ classes and wrap this in a native DLL. I have the header of the native DLL which specifies 4 functions that the library must expose to some application. I have just the CLR DLL, no sources included. Can someone tell me which is the most straightforward and easy way to achieve this? Currently I am using Visual Studio 2015 Express but I can move to any version that is free. Can you provide some concrete steps as to how I can do this?

Comment: What doesmthe CLR DLL do?  Are you open to using COM?

Comment: The CLR Dll exposes some classes and methods that allow me to control a slave device on RS232. Directly implementing communication with device is out of question given the timeframe and lack of specifications. I'll use COM if I have to but before posting this question I've read a bit about COM and it appears to be more than a mouthful.

Comment: You may want to give us more information. What _do_ you know about the CLR DLL? If you can't figure it out _with_ that information, how are we supposed to figure it out _without_ ?!

Comment: Ok, what info should i provide that would be helpful?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10020/Using-managed-code-in-an-unmanaged-application

Wrapping in unmanaged interface through use of factories and derived classes.